# Prop not used properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I´m getting the error that setAnimals is not a function. I controlled every prop but i can´t find the mistake

Form code:

```
export default function AddAnimalForm({setAnimals, animals}) {
  const [submitMessage, setSubmitMessage] = useState(false);
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
    event.target.reset();
    const newAnimal = { ...data, id: uid() };
    setAnimals([...(animals || []), newAnimal]); 
    setSubmitMessage(true);
    setShowDetails(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSubmitMessage(false);
      setShowDetails(false);
    }, 3000);
  };
```

App.js code:

```
import GlobalStyle from "@/styles";
import Head from "next/head";
import useLocalStorageState from "use-local-storage-state";
import Link from "next/link";
import StyledButton from "@/components/Navigation"


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useLocalStorageState("animals", []);

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Head>
        <title>Capstone Project</title>
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} animals={animals} setAnimals={setAnimals} />
```

As far as I can see I gave it properly to every page necessary.

Comment: You're not putting the form component into your App component

Comment: Dunno if I understood it correct but the Component is getting all the props or do you mean i have to import the Form?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Component {...pageProps, animals, setAnimals}/>
```

But I would suggest creating a react context and wrap the `<Component/>` with a provider.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can´t use context for this.
Your code didn´t work out the problem sadly. Thank your for the try tho!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.. I didn´t give the props to the actual page.